# Haskell: Parsing a file finishes after first expression despite more input in file

Tags: parsing, haskell

The following is an example program of a language in which I'm writing a parser.

```
n := 1  
Do (1)->          -- The 1 in brackets is a placeholder for a Boolean or relational expression.
        n := 1 + 1
Od
```

When the program looks like this, the `parseFile` functions ends after the assignment on the first line however when the assignment is removed, it parses as expected. Below is how it's called in `GHCI`, first with the first line present then removed:

```
λ > parseFile "example.hnry"
Assign "n" (HInteger 1)

λ > parseFile "example.hnry"
Do (HInteger 1) (Assign "n" (AExpr (HInteger 1) Add (HInteger 1)))
```

The expected output would look similar to this:

```
λ > parseFile "example.hnry"
Assign "n" (HInteger 1) Do (HInteger 1) (Assign "n" (AExpr (HInteger 1) Add (HInteger 1)))
```

I first assumed it was something to do with the the assignment parser but in the body of the loop, there exists an assignment which parses as expected so I was able to rule that out. I believe that the issue is within the `parseFile` function itself. The following is the `parseFile` function and the other functions that make up the `parseExpression` function that I'm using to parse a program.

I think that the error is within `parseFile` because it parses an expression only once and doesn't "loop" for the want of a better word to itself to check if there's more input left the parse. I think that's the error but I'm not quite sure.

```
parseFile :: String -> IO HVal
parseFile file =
    do program <- readFile file
           case parse parseExpression "" program of
        Left  err    -> fail "Parse Error"
        Right parsed -> return $ parsed

parseExpression :: Parser HVal
parseExpression = parseAExpr <|> parseDo <|> parseAssign

parseDo :: Parser HVal
parseDo = do
   _  <- string "Do "
   _  <- char '('
   x  <- parseHVal  -- Will be changed to a Boolean expression
   _  <- string ")->"
   spaces
   y  <- parseExpression
   spaces
   _  <- string "Od"
   return $ Do x y

parseAExpr :: Parser HVal
parseAExpr = do
   x  <- parseInteger
   spaces
   op <- parseOp
   spaces
   y  <- parseInteger <|> do
                _ <- char '('
                z <- parseAExpr
                            _ <- char ')'
                            return $ z
   return $ AExpr x op y

parseAssign :: Parser HVal
parseAssign = do
 var <- oneOf ['a'..'z'] <|> oneOf ['A'..'Z']
 spaces
 _   <- string ":="
 spaces
 val <- parseHVal <|> do
                    _ <- char '('
                        z <- parseAExpr
                        _ <- char ')'
                        return $ z
 return $ Assign [var] val
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you note, your `parseFile` function parses a single expression (though maybe "statement" would be a better name) using the `parseExpression` parser.  You probably want to introduce a new parser for a "program" or sequence of expressions/statements:

```
parseProgram :: Parser [HVal]
parseProgram = spaces *> many (parseExpression <* spaces)
```

and then in `parseFile`, replace `parseExpression` with `parseProgram`:

```
parseFile :: String -> IO [HVal]
parseFile file =
    do program <- readFile file
       case parse parseProgram "" program of
         Left  err    -> fail "Parse Error"
         Right parsed -> return $ parsed
```

Note that I've had to change the type here from `HVal` to `[HVal]` to reflect the fact that a program, being a sequence of expressions each of type `HVal`, needs to be represented as some sort of data type capable of combining multiple `HVal`s together, and a list `[HVal]` is one way of doing so.

If you want a program to be an `HVal` instead of an `[HVal]`, then you need to introduce a new constructor in your `HVal` type that's capable of representing programs.  One method is to use a constructor to directly represent a block of statements:

```
data HVal = ... | Block [HVal]
```

Another is to add a constructor represent a sequence of two statements:

```
data HVal = ... | Seq HVal HVal
```

Both methods are used in real parsers.  (Note that you'd normally pick one; you wouldn't use both.)  To represent a sequence of three assignment statements, for example, the block method would do it directly as a list:

```
Block [Assign "a" (HInteger 1), Assign "b" (HInteger 2), Assign "c" (HInteger 3)]
```

while the two-statement sequence method would build a sort of nested tree:

```
Seq (Assign "a" (HInteger 1)) (Seq (Assign "b" (HInteger 2)
                                   (Assign "c" (HInteger 3))
```

The appropriate parsers for these two alternatives, both of which return a plain `HVal`, might be:

```
-- use blocks
parseProgram1 :: Parser HVal
parseProgram1 = do
  spaces
  xs <- many (parseExpression <* spaces)
  return $ Block xs

parseProgram2 :: Parser HVal
parseProgram2 = do
  spaces
  x <- parseExpression
  spaces
  (do xs <- parseProgram2
      return $ Seq x xs)
    <|> return x
```

Comment: Could I ask why `IO HVal` was changed to `IO [HVal]` and why `parseProgram` is `Parser [HVal]` ?

Comment: @JiangShi You did not show how `HVal` is defined: I guess there we can find some way to compose statements, so that `[HVal]` can be turned into a single `HVal`. What is the expected output for two assignments like `n:=1 ; m:=2`, for instance? You likely want to modify your parser accordingly, so to parse code blocks right (e.g. inside a `Do`) using `many` or something similar. After that, you can return `Parser HVal`.

Comment: @K.A.Buhr That explanation is amazing! Thank you!